# Modify Program Using Sync Framework to use WCF

Tags: wcf, frameworks, synchronization

I'm trying to synchronize a client database with a central database.  I successfully did that using the Synchronization framework as long as both the client and central database are on the same network.  However, I need for this to work with the client being outside the network and the firewall.  The firewall prevents communications on port 1433, so I started to explore WCF as an option so port 80 is used.

I tried this and put the WCF service under IIS 7:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208

but have gotten this error:

Failed: The caller was not authenticated by the service.

I searched high and low for a solution to this error but have found none.  Does anyone know a tutorial on how to use the sync framework over WCF?

Here is the web.config file on the IIS server:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WebSyncContract.SqlWebSyncService" name="WebSyncContract.SqlWebSyncService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessageHttpBinding" contract="WebSyncContract.ISqlSyncContract">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://web-services.hexagroup.us/WebSyncContract.SqlWebSyncService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="WebSyncContract.SqlSyncProviderProxy" behaviorConfiguration="WebSyncContract.SqlSyncProviderProxy" >
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WebSyncContract.SyncService" name="WebSyncContract.SyncService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessageHttpBinding" contract="WebSyncContract.ISyncContract">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>-->
        <add baseAddress="http://web-services.hexagroup.us/WebSyncContract.SqlWebSyncService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <!-- We are using Server cert only.-->
    <binding name="largeMessageHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" />

      <!--<reliableSession enabled="true" />
      <security mode="None" />-->       
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebSyncContract.SqlWebSyncService">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  <behavior name="WebSyncContract.SqlSyncProviderProxy" >
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="WebSyncContract.SyncService" >
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check your WCF config for things related to security

Comment: I just posted the contents of the web.config file.  I tried changing the binding from wsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding but got an error saying a session is required.